# Extract a particular number from a string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

Here is my string

INPUT:

```
22 TIRES (2 defs)

1 AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)

6 CHIC ("SHEIK" hom)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
22 TIRES

1 APPEARANCE

6 CHIC
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT :

```
TIRES

APPEARANCE

CHIC
```

I tried using below code and got the above output.

```
String firstnames =a.split(" \\(.*")[0].replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" + ",
                        "");
```

Any idea of how to extract along with the numbers ? I don't want the numbers which are after the parentheses like in the input " 22 TIRES (2 defs)". I need the output as "22 TIRES" Any help would be great !!

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single replaceAll function.

```
str.replaceAll("\\s+\\(.*|\\s*\\+\\s*|[()]", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gC8lB4/1)

- `\\s+\\(.*`, this matches a space and and the following `(` characters plus all the remaining characters which follows this pattern. So `(CAN anag)` part in your example got matched.
- `\\s*\\+\\s*` matches `+` along with the preceding and following spaces.
- `[()]` matches opening or closing brackets.
- Atlast all the matched chars are replaced by empty string.

Comment: It works  !! Could you please explain how it works? @Avinash Raj

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the code does @Avinash Raj

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it bit differently

```
String line = "22 TIRES (2 defs)\n\n1 AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)\n\n6 CHIC (\"SHEIK\" hom)"; 
String pattern = "(\\d+\\s+)(.*)\\(";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    String tmp = m.group(1) + m.group(2).replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/aZ4VRF)**